# How to make counter 0.5 seconds per count for Mini CPR project on arduino UNO board (Arduino IDE)

Tags: c++, arduino

I have a project for mini CPR project using an Arduino UNO board. After uploading the code, I noticed that the counter is 0.8 seconds per count... It need should be 0.5 seconds for each count. Does anyone have any idea how to modify it?

```
void loop() {
  timer = millis() / 1000;
  unsigned long C_time = timer - E_time;
   // Check if the reset button is pressed
    if (digitalRead(resetButton) == LOW) {
      cycle = 0;
      counter = 0;
      E_time = millis()/1000;
    }
if (millis() - timeNOW >= refresh) {
  weight = hx711.get_units(10) - offset;
    // If the calibrate button is pressed, calibrate the scale
if (digitalRead(calibrateButton) == LOW) {
    int C_weight = weight;
    offset = offset + C_weight;
  }

  timeNOW = millis(); 
    // Display weight on the first line of the LCD
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("Weight: " + String(weight) + " kg     ");
  Serial.print("\n Weight: " + String(weight) + " kg");

  // Display the counter and timer on the second line of the LCD
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print("CNT:" + String(counter) + " Time:" + String(C_time) +"      ");
  Serial.print("\t Counter: " + String(counter) + " \t Timer: " + String(C_time) + "\t Cycle: " + String(cycle));
  }

    // Update counter every 0.5 seconds
    if (millis() - prevTime >= intervalCNT) { 
  // If the weight is greater than 20kg, start counting and start the timer
  if (weight >= 20){
      prevTime = millis();
      counter++;
    }
```

Comment: This is not the way to design time critical microcontroler routine (even assuming that the code is logically correct, which I am not sure about). `millis();` only gives you a rough estimate of how much time has passed since some arbitrary point and it has no real-time guarantees. Read the arduino docs or some tutorials on how to properly use timers and counters.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48043559/4165552

Comment: Try to remove code from your example that is not necessary to reproduce the problem. For example the calibration block. The values you compare against are also unknown, such as `refresh` and `intervalCNT`

Answer (score 0):

I guess that before the updateCounter block runs, also the the refresh block runs. Assuming that all the serial and lcd output take some time, the actual execution of your last block is always too late. Try to swap the last two blocks:

```
void loop() {
  timer = millis() / 1000;
  unsigned long C_time = timer - E_time;
  // Check if the reset button is pressed
  if (digitalRead(resetButton) == LOW) {
    cycle = 0;
    counter = 0;
    E_time = millis()/1000;
  }

  // Update counter every 0.5 seconds BEFORE writing to lcd and serial
  if (millis() - prevTime >= intervalCNT) { 
    // If the weight is greater than 20kg, start counting and start the timer
    if (weight >= 20){
      prevTime = millis();
      counter++;
    }

  if (millis() - timeNOW >= refresh) {
  weight = hx711.get_units(10) - offset;
  // If the calibrate button is pressed, calibrate the scale
  if (digitalRead(calibrateButton) == LOW) {
    int C_weight = weight;
    offset = offset + C_weight;
  }

  timeNOW = millis(); 
  // Display weight on the first line of the LCD
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("Weight: " + String(weight) + " kg     ");
  Serial.print("\n Weight: " + String(weight) + " kg");

  // Display the counter and timer on the second line of the LCD
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print("CNT:" + String(counter) + " Time:" + String(C_time) +"      ");
  Serial.print("\t Counter: " + String(counter) + " \t Timer: " + String(C_time) + "\t Cycle: " + String(cycle));
  }
```